# trying to delete a file in Temp dir using CreateProcessA

Tags: c++

Hello I am trying to delete a file using following code:

```
CreateProcessA(NULL, (LPSTR)"del /f C:\\Users\\samee\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tempFile.txt", 0, 0, true, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, 0, 0, &si, &pi);
```

however this is not working. What am doing wrong here?

Comment: Use [`std::remove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/remove) or [`std::filesystem::remove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/remove).

Comment: im using C++ 14 sadly

Comment: The former exists in C++14.

Comment: and all the way back, if you ignore the `std` namespace, to pre-ANSI Standardized C. `remove` is oooooooold.

Comment: I believe the problem is that `del` is not a process you can create, it's a built in command to the Windows Command Shell.

Comment: [`DeleteFileA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-deletefile) ?

Answer (score 2):

`del` is not an executable that you can run directly.  It is a built-in command of the `cmd.exe` shell.  So, you would need to run `cmd.exe` instead, using its `/C` or `/K` parameter to execute shell commands, eg:

```
char cmdLine[] = "cmd.exe /C del /f C:\\Users\\samee\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tempFile.txt";
CreateProcessA(NULL, cmdLine, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
```

But why do that?  The Win32 API has a [`DeleteFileA()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-deletefilea) function, you should use that instead, eg:

```
DeleteFileA("C:\\Users\\samee\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tempFile.txt");
```

Note that the `/f` parameter of `del` allows for deleting a read-only file. If `DeleteFileA()` fails because the file is read-only, then simply remove the read-only flag, eg:

```
char fileName[] = "C:\\Users\\samee\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tempFile.txt";

DWORD attr = GetFileAttributesA(fileName);
if ((attr != INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES) && (attr & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY))
    SetFileAttributesA(fileName, attr & ~FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY);

DeleteFileA(fileName);
```